# Dpkg cant purge AMD-graphics package; read-only file system (Mint)

Tags: permissions, linux-mint, dpkg, x-server, amd-graphics

For reasons regarding the other question I asked on here I want to purge the package xserver-xorg-v from my Linux Mint from the root shell. I get the following Error: `dpkg -P xserver-xorg-v dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: Read-only file system`

What is a command to find out which file system this is on and make that file system not read-only/how do I purge this thing?

Comment: Welcome on the Unix SE! What does an `mkdir g`? Can it create a directory named `g`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deb packages are stored in /var/cache/apt/archives. Check there.

But if you're in recovery mode it's not surprising that the archive directory is read only. I saw your other question and just answered it. Don't bother purging packages when you just need to move your xorg.conf file to default back to using the open source driver for your video card.

To make the directory not read only you need only do this:

```
# mount -o remount rw /var/cache/apt/archives
```

But again, this is just for educational purposes only since I highly recommend you not be shooting fish in a barrel trying to purge packages with dpkg in recovery mode. Do it properly with the MINT package manager after you reboot with a video card. Or else you're just going to end up hosing your system even more since dpkg will only remove one package and won't bother with all the dependencies.

Comment: the line you suggested resulted in "bad option". I was able to make the directory read only using mount -o remount,rw /